# lightence-ant-design-react-template run issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am a newbie in reactJS. i am trying to use lightence-ant-design.
https://github.com/altence/lightence-ant-design-react-template/tree/main
I followed the steps below as per the instructions in the github:

To go with the latest version please copy and past in your terminal the following steps

git clone https://github.com/altence/lightence-ant-design-react-template.git my-awesome-project && cd my-awesome-project

Development mode

yarn install && yarn start

here when i use yarn start command i am getting the error :

```
Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported
    at new Hash (node:internal/crypto/hash:68:19)
    at Object.createHash (node:crypto:138:10)
    at module.exports (/..../node_modules/webpack/lib/util/createHash.js:135:53)
    at NormalModule._initBuildHash (/..../node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:417:16)
    at handleParseError (/..../node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:471:10)
    at /..../node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:503:5
    at /..../node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:358:12
    at /..../node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:373:3
    at iterateNormalLoaders (/..../node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:214:10)
    at iterateNormalLoaders (/..../node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:221:10)
/..../node_modules/react-scripts/scripts/start.js:19
  throw err;
  ^

Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported
    at new Hash (node:internal/crypto/hash:68:19)
    at Object.createHash (node:crypto:138:10)
    at module.exports (/..../node_modules/webpack/lib/util/createHash.js:135:53)
    at NormalModule._initBuildHash (/..../node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:417:16)
    at /..../node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:452:10
    at /..../node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:323:13
    at /..../node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:367:11
    at /..../node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:233:18
    at context.callback (/..../node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:111:13)
    at /..../node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js:59:103 {
  opensslErrorStack: [ 'error:03000086:digital envelope routines::initialization error' ],
  library: 'digital envelope routines',
  reason: 'unsupported',
  code: 'ERR_OSSL_EVP_UNSUPPORTED'
}
```

Node.js v20.11.0

Can anyone help me to solve this ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Project is 2 years old, you can use nodejs 16  or run project with:

```
export NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider
```

Also there is broken dependency `round-slider`